# How to create a POSCAR for hexagonal structure for VASP calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

The method that I am following in creating a hexagonal lattice POSCAR file is by downloading it from https://materialsproject.org/ website. Now, I want to learn how to create it manually starting from given information in an article. Could someone of you give me a detailed method to do that?
Please be detailed and thank you in advance for devoting time to read and answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the software VESTA to create the structure as mentioned [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/409/88) and export the structure to POSCAR

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer is very useful. Could explain to me what is Ueq? And what are the key words to search for atomic coordinates of a given material?

Comment: Its the displacement parameter. https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/426/88

Comment: What about how to find atomic coordinates ? And those tables shown in your mentionned post?

Comment: @ChiKou. You should look whether its available in literature. Or as an alternative  this [post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1/88) might be useful